# How get content of all element with same class name?

Tags: javascript, function, class, get, innerhtml

Get content of all elements with the same class name using javascript.
How can I get all innerHTML-content from elements with the same class? I tried the code described below but it doesn't work I only get the first "Hello" from element but I don't get "World! from the second element" Of course there will be many more elements with the same class, not just two.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var child = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
  var child, i;
  for (i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
    var childall = child[i].innerHTML;
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = childall;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="child">Hello</div>
  <div class="child" id="child">World!</div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
<div class="demo" id="demo">
```

Comment: `var childall += child[i].innerHTML;` - You should use `+=` to append the new content onto your existing `childall` value. You should also move your `childall` declaration outside of your for loop and just add to it inside.

Comment: declare `var childall = "";` outside your loop. Then append the `innerHTML` to childall using `+=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `childall` out of the loop, and assign an array to it. Now push all innerHTML values into it. After the loop ends join the array to a string, and assign to demo.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var child = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
  var child, i;
  var childall = [];
  for (i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
    childall.push(child[i].innerHTML);
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = childall.join('<br>');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="child">Hello</div>
  <div class="child" id="child">World!</div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
<div class="demo" id="demo">
```

Instead of a for loop, you can use `Array.from()` to get an array of children's `innerHTML`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const childall = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".child"), el => el.innerHTML);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = childall.join('<br>');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="child">Hello</div>
  <div class="child" id="child">World!</div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
<div class="demo" id="demo">
```

Comment: Thank you
This works great. But how to get the word "World!" be below "Hello", not next to ..., i try with <br> but nathing...